# On the electric field of a parallel plate capacitor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-fields, capacitance

Recently, solving a math problem that somehow was related to an electron in a plate capacitor, I remembered a question I once had in High School and never solved:

Since I am no physicist, I will keep it rather simple. Suppose you are given a plate capacitor with voltage $10$V, plate distance $10$cm and capacitance $1$F$\implies Q=10$C. Consider now an electron between the plates (in the middle). If we wish to evaluate the electric field $E$ at the electron's location, we could use the well-known formula $$E=\frac{F}{q_1}=\frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\cdot \frac{Q}{r^2}=\frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\cdot \frac{10C}{r^2}\tag{1}$$ where $r$ stays for the distance between electron and plate. Yet, since we are dealing with a plate capacitor -and hence a homogenous field- we could use another approach: $$E=\frac{U}{d}=\frac{10V}{0.01m}\tag{2}$$

Here the question

> The formula $(1)$ suggest that $E$ depends on $r$, i.e., $E$ varies whenever you move the electron, whereas $(2)$ implies that $E$ is constant and does not depend on $r$ -which somehow makes sense taking into consideration the definition of *homogeneous field*.

What am I missing?

Comment: Eqn (1) applies if $Q$ and $q_1$ are both *point charges*. The electric field is radial. In the capacitor $Q$ is *not* a point charge. It is spread evenly over each plate of the capacitor. Eqn (2) applies is the correct eqn to use for the homogenous field between the plates of the capacitor.

Comment: It is important in physics to understand when certain equations apply. Please do not think "The electric field is always given by $kQ/r^2$". Electric fields do not look like this for general systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coulomb found that if you have two stationary point charges then the force can be found using: 
$$F_C=\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\cdot \frac{q\cdot Q}{r^2}$$

If you have a test object (with charge $Q$) which can be treated as a point charge then a positive test charge (with charge $q$) would experience a force that is inverse  proportional to $r^2$ with direction on the line that goes thru the two points.

If you have a situation where you instead of one point charge have say five point charges, then you would again apply Coulomb's law, but together with the [superposition principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle) you would add the contribution from each charge to find the net force on a positive test charge $q$ (by convention).

If you have millions of millions of ... of point charges, a very realistic scenario, you could in principle apply Coulomb's law and the superposition principle, however it becomes impractical. Instead the concept of electric field is applied together with Gauss' law.

Reason for using the quantity electric field instead of force is that force depends on the test charge $q_1$. By introducing electric field, $E$, which is defined as: 
$$E=\frac{F_E}{q}$$
you get an quantity which is independent of the test charge. Note $F_E$ is now the net force on the test charge $q$

Scientists have analyzed different scenarios and found the electric field for these (using Gauss' law). Now, you can rearrange above equation and use $E$ as cause and $F_E$ as effect: 
$$F_E=E\cdot q$$

Back to the parallel plate capacitor.

Assume a large positively charged plate at the top and a large negatively charged plate at the bottom.

If you place a positive test charge between the two plates it will experience a repulsive force from a point charge just above it and an attractive force from a point charge just below it. In the middle these two forces would be equal in size and direction.

If the test charge is moved down, the upper force will be smaller but the lower force will be larger.

If instead the test charge is moved above the middle, the upper force will be stronger and the lower force will be smaller.

This indicates that the force may be independent of distance to the places, however we are not there yet. Next you would have to consider the effect from more charges from the plates i.e. those that are not directly north or south of the test charge. Summing all these up the net force now becomes independent of distance from the two plates.

You could in principle try this out with 10 point charges on each plate and see how close it gets. 100 would be better, 1000 even better. It soon becomes evident that Gauss law is brilliant for determining E fields.